# Hello World with FlashDevelop, Flixel, AS3: uneffective SWF macro

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flixel, flex, flashdevelop

I just started with FlashDevelop and Flixel, and I already have a question. I created this basic hello world:

```
package  
{
    import org.flixel.*;
    [SWF(width = "640", height = "480", backgroundColor = "#000000")]; //Set the size and color of the Flash file

    public class HelloWorld extends FlxGame
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I run this "game", using Flash Player, I get a 800x600 window with a white background, even though I specified it's 640x480 with a black background. Am I doing anything wrong?

I am using Flex 4.6.0, and the target platform is Flash Player 10.1. I have the debugger version of Flash Player 11 installed (WIN 11,5,502,146 to be exact).

---

In the `.xml` file (found in the `obj` folder) I found the following:

```
<default-size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
</default-size>
```

Changing the size/color through the properties window of my FlashDevelop project **does** work fine...

It seems to ignore the `[SWF(...)]` macro entirely: what's going on?

Comment: This looks correct. I compared it to some code from when I used Flixel in 2011, and although `Game` (my version) became `FlxGame` (your version), everything else looks fine.

Comment: Not sure, but usually the meta information `[SWF(...` should be directly above the class definition. Try removing that blank line in between and retry?

Comment: ... also try to remove the spaces between your equal signs (eg. `width="640"` instead of `width = "640"`). Not sure how nitpicky the compiler is when it comes to these meta-tags, but it seems to ignore yours.

Comment: @bummzack, hi again ^_^ you're right, the compiler is really annoying with these tags. I've found my answer, posted it below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It was the semicolon (`;`) after the `[SWF(...)]` that killed it. Got it rocking now :) I believe the FLEX compiler is to blame here, since [tutorials](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/flixel/wiki/Hello,-World!-%28FlashDevelop%29) also have this semicolon, they'll probably used the Flash IDE...

Comment: Ah, right. This is in case somebody finds a better answer, to keep some appeal for the question. In this case, well, I doubt this will happen ;)